# MLE of $\mu$ given $X_1\sim \mathsf N(\mu, 4)$ and $X_2\sim \mathsf{N}(\mu, 16)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X_1\sim \mathsf N(\mu, 4)$ and $X_2\sim \mathsf{N}(\mu, 16)$
>   where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.  Find the maximum likelihood
>   estimator $\hat{\mu}$ of $\mu$ if it exists.

We have

$$\begin{align*}
L(\mu\mid x_1, x_2)
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x_1-\mu)^2}{8}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{32\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x_2-\mu)^2}{32}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}\sqrt{32\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x_1-\mu)^2}{8}-\frac{(x_2-\mu)^2}{32}}
\end{align*}$$

Then

$$logL(\mu\mid x_1, x_2)=log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}\sqrt{32\pi}}\right)-\frac{(x_1-\mu)^2}{8}-\frac{(x_2-\mu)^2}{32}$$

Then we set

$$\frac{\partial log(L)}{\partial\mu}=\frac{1}{4}(x_1-\mu)+\frac{1}{16}(x_2-\mu)=0$$

Solving for $\mu$ I get that $\hat{\mu}=\frac{4}{5}x_1+\frac{1}{5}x_2$

This doesn't satisfy my intuition. I would have thought $\hat{\mu}=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$

Checking that this is in fact a maximum, I get that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\mu}\left(\frac{1}{4}(x_1-\mu)+\frac{1}{16}(x_2-\mu)\right)=-\frac{5}{16}\lt0\text{ } \checkmark$$

Is this a valid solution?

**Edit:**

I think the MLE makes sense actually. It gives more weight to the random variable with a lower variance.

Comment: You edit says it all!

Comment: @Vincent But the result is not right in general.

Comment: Wait, how do you mean in general? If the ratio between variances is not 2 but something else the ratio between the 'weights' mentioned in the edit will not be 4, but the random variable with smaller variance will still have the larger weight. How could this be any different?

Comment: @Vincent See my answer. Since it is not mentioned that n is a specific number it is better to use the general case where the sample size is n for both variables. That is the standard method if the sample size is not known/specified.

Comment: Yes but you arrive at the same conclusion. Your MLE (which I agree is better) could be written as a sum over all observations where the ones coming from the distribution with smaller variance are multiplied by 4 and where the denominator is $5n$. As in the $n = 1$ case derived by the OP, we see that the random variable with smaller variance is getting more weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is not right in my opinion. Note that you have a sample size of $n$. The likelihood function is

$$L(\mu | x_{11},x_{12},\ldots,x_{1n},x_{21},x_{22},\ldots,x_{2n})=\prod_{i=1}^n \left( \frac1{16\cdot \Pi}\right)\cdot \Large{e^{-\frac{(x_{1i}-\mu)^2}{8}+\frac{(x_{2i}-\mu)^2}{32}}}$$

$$=\left( \frac1{16\cdot \Pi}\right)^n\cdot \prod_{i=1}^n  \Large{e^{-\frac{(x_{1i}-\mu)^2}{8}+\frac{(x_{2i}-\mu)^2}{32}}}$$

Taking logs

$$-n\cdot \ln (16\cdot \Pi)-\sum_{i=1}^n\left( \frac{(x_{1i}-\mu)^2}{8}+\frac{(x_{2i}-\mu)^2}{32} \right)$$

Taking derivative w.r.t. $\mu$ and set it equal to $0$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left( 2\cdot \frac{x_{1i}-\mu}{8}+2\cdot \frac{x_{2i}-\mu}{32} \right)=0$$

$$\frac14\sum_{i=1}x_{1i}+\frac1{16}\sum_{i=1}x_{2i}=\frac5{16}\cdot n\cdot \mu$$

$$\frac4{16}\sum_{i=1}x_{1i}+\frac1{16}\sum_{i=1}x_{2i}=\frac5{16}\cdot n\cdot \mu \quad |\cdot 16$$

$$4\sum_{i=1}x_{1i}+\sum_{i=1}x_{2i}=5\cdot n\cdot \mu \quad $$

Then we use $\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_{1i}=\overline{x_1} \Rightarrow \sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_{1i}=n\cdot \overline{x_1}$ Similar for the sample of $X_2$

$$4n\cdot \overline{x_1}+n\cdot \overline{x_2}=5\cdot n\cdot \mu \qquad |:n$$

$$4\cdot \overline{x_1}+ \overline{x_2}=5\cdot  \mu $$

Dividing the equation by 5 we obtain the MLE for $\mu$

$$\boxed{\hat \mu=\frac{4\cdot \overline{x_1}+ \overline{x_2}}{5}}$$

So you take a sample of $n$ from both distributions each and  with the sample means, $\overline{x_1}$ and $\overline{x_2}$, you can estimate $\mu$.

Comment: The question says $n=2$, i.e. a sample $X=(X_1,X_2)$ of size $2$. You have assumed $X_1=(X_{11},X_{12},\ldots,X_{1n})$ and $X_2=(X_{21},X_{22},\ldots,X_{2n})$ are two independent samples each of size $n$, in which case the likelihood function should be denoted as $L(\mu\mid x_{11},\ldots,x_{1n},x_{21},\ldots,x_{2n})$.

Comment: That´s true. The notation is not right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: But $X_1$ and $X_2$ are single observations, not samples themselves. If it were so, the question statement should have mentioned it. Your work says there is a sample of size $2n$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom No, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $\textrm{random variables}$. Sure for n=1 you would get what the OP has posted, but at the exercise it is not written that $n=1$.

Comment: Of course they are random variables. And there is no $n$ in the question.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The general case is a sample size of $n$. This is what you use if n is not specified. But you cannot set n=1 for the general case. I think it isn´t hard to understand.

Comment: It is a little hard to understand why should I go through the general case if I am asked about a specific case.

Comment: `@StubbornAtom Where do you read that $n=1$?

Comment: As I said, I don't read any $n$ whatsoever. Except that the sample size is $2$ here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Where do you read that the sample size is 2?

Comment: I apologize. I should have specified. This should be treated as a sample of size 2.